# Options for permanently joining two flexible printed circuits (FPC) together?

Tags: interconnect, fpc

Robust, simple and cheap method to join a pair of flex pcbs / flex printed circuits (fpc) together?

One option could be making both circuits rigid-flex then joining as one would two pcbs, which would then be standard.

How is this best done?

edit: this is for **permanently** joining, not via a connector

Comment: By "joining" do you mean with a connector, or permanently?

Answer (score 1):

Without dispute, best way will be designing the whole part as flex, or rigid-flex. When not preferred these methods for some reason, it may be designed suitable for soldering...with a method like hot-bar soldering.

[image: Flex Hot Bar Soldering]

Answer (score 1):

What I have used, and seen in the past, is using ACF bonding + glue (not good in hot environments), while the other method that I've used is using solder to join the parts. The first method is also called Hot Bar Bonding, while the second is commonly called Hot bar soldering. I have seen this second method used on Samsung phones to join the Touch screen flex onto the LCD Flex.

If you need extra strength, you should also add some mechanical form of holding the two parts together, such as a clamp, which will however add weight to the flex.